Shopware 6 - core.app.shopId in system_config.yaml to set the default configuration
I am using system_config.yaml to set the default configuration. I need to set the value of core.app.shopId but when I try to do:
core.app.shopId.value: '%env(SHOP_ID)%'
looks like it is working but when I logged in to the admin and tried to save the configuration in settings > basic Information I faced an error:
Expected domain
As I understand this correctly domain should be core.app.shopId but in my yaml is core.app.shopId.value and this is not passing the domain validation.
I also tried to add the array:
core app.shopId:
                     value: '%env(SHOP_ID)%'

But I faced the error:
Invalid type for path "shopware.system_config.default.core.app.shopId". Expected "scalar", but got "array".

Maybe someone knows how to achieve this?

You need to configure core.app.shopId directly as a simple scalar value in the system_config.yaml, referencing the environment variable properly. Here's how to do it:
yaml
shopware:
  system_config:
    default:
      core.app.shopId: '%env(SHOP_ID)%'

Explanation:
core.app.shopId is set directly to the value of the environment variable SHOP_ID.
There's no need to use value or any nested structure—this avoids the domain validation issue.

First of all, thank you for your response.
Yes, correct this works perfectly fine for scalar values like shopName etc. Unfortunately, shopId is a JSON object stored in the database and contains APP_URL and value and I can't just override everything by scalar value.
To anticipate the idea, add it to the env JSON:  core app.shopId: json_value
This works the same as string. I will only get a string with a JSON value without converting it into an array.
